# Sending a link to Instapaper FROM a Kindle

Tags: kindle, instapaper

Say you are surfing using the Kindle 3's *actually-pretty-good* web browser, and you want to read something later, or perhaps the page contains video or something else that the Kindle can't display.

How could you send a link to your Instapaper account FROM your Kindle (3)?

The browser has bookmarks but I don't know how to get Instapaper's bookmarklet in to there since it's JavaScript, or even if that would work.

Comment: +1 for getting `instapaper` added as a tag!

Comment: I don't know about you, but any video worth viewing is probably only a google or two away.

Comment: @digitxp That assumes that you're anywhere near a video capable device at the time. Instapaper is great for reminding yourself about things a day or so later when it's more convenient.

Comment: @GAThrawn You probably are if you have WiFi to surf the web on. It's not often when you go to a coffee shop without your phone.

Comment: @digit It is quite often that I'm lying in bed reading on my Kindle with no other electronic device more complicated than a clock in the room, and no desire to get out from under my warm duvet in the next 8 hours!

Comment: @GAThrawn Cough notebook cough. ;-)

Comment: @digitxp The Kindle has 3G cellular data access, apart from the cheapest model. I have never needed a WiFi hotspot.

Comment: @frou The Kindle 3 lets you browse over 3G?

Comment: @digitxp Yes, and for free, there's no contract like a phone.

Comment: @Frou It wouldn't let me do that on my Kindle 3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a way to send links to Instapaper FROM my Kindle, based on a tip I read here: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=1315115#post1315115.

1) When you're on a page you want to add to Instapaper, using the "Enter URL" option on your Kindle, cursor to the beginning of the address, and type in "tinyurl.com/create.php?url="  (it's short enough to memorize so you can do it quickly).  You now have the address you added AND the page address in the URL box together. Press "Enter" to take you to the tinyurl.com URL-shortening page.

2) Assign each page a name following some system you make up using VERY SHORT names that you can REMEMBER (such as "jan0120111" for the first file you want to send on Jan 1, 2011). You might want to put a random letter in there somewhere to make it more likely no one else will be using your filenames!

3) Go to your email account on your Kindle, in which you've already set up a contact for the long, weird email address of your Instapaper account.

4) Send an email to that address, in the body of which you've typed the shortened name you've just assigned to the page you wanted to send.

The page will be added to your Instapaper account.  It's hardly a streamlined, one-click solution, but it does work and doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I'm sorry to say my solution below does not actually work well. First of all most url shorteners don't support adding parameters. Secondly the instapaper api is a little more complicated and required some fiddling. I was able to rig it up using my own domain and a custom written script, but it's not a cut and paste solution because the script has to be authenticated against my account. I'll keep working on a solution for this one.

---

Instapaper's bookmarklet works via a GET url that gets called with details about the page you are looking at. The main bit of this is the URL, something like this:

http://www.instapaper.com/j/XtBngZd2JICG?u=YOUR_PAGE_URL

There are some other values that get passed like the title and such, but you could probably standardize those, like t=from_my_kindle, etc.

Now all you need to do is type in all that BEFORE the url in the address bar of the kindle. Of course that's clumsy, so get the URL all setup with a title and whatnot but so that it ends with the &u=, then use a URL shortener that supports extra arguments so that on your kindle you could edit the url to say http://short.ner/surl/http://site.you.were.on/blah/blah

I don't have my kindle handy to try this right nowc an't try this right now but will check it later...

Comment: Thanks, Caleb. If only the Kindle OS had copy and paste, this would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Can you send an e-mail with a link from the Kindle Browser? I don't have a Kindle myself so I can't check, but I've used Instapaper's add by e-mail feature from other places. At http://www.instapaper.com/extras you can get your special e-mail address to send links or long e-mails to.

Comment: Nope, no email. I guess the thing about Kindle is that the web browser itself is billed as an 'experimental' value-add, so it's hard to be annoyed about the lack of other computery features and conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer if you want to send arbitrary pages to Instapaper, but "Read Later with Instapaper" type links that are already in web pages work fine in the Kindle browser.

For instance the "Read" links on [GiveMeSomethingToRead.com](http://givemesomethingtoread.com/) work in the Kindle browser.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to your Instapaper account from your Kindle browser.
2. Append the following string before the url of the article you wish to save.

> https://www.instapaper.com/text?u=

The 'https://' part is required. 
You can also use a shortner like tiny.cc which accepts arguments in url to further reduce your typing.

3. From the Instapaper page that opens next, click save to Instapaper button.

Sample url:

https://www.instapaper.com/text?u=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog

*(You must be logged into your Instapaper account for this to work)*